# Prove that $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\dfrac{n^{3}+1}{n^{4}+4}=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, inequality

Prove that $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\dfrac{n^{3}+1}{n^{4}+4}=0$ . I'll write the question without epsilon because I write definition on my paper. I just stuck where I wrote.

$\dfrac{n^{3}+1}{n^{4}+4} <\dfrac{n^{3}+1}{n^{4}} <\dfrac{n^{3}+n^{2}}{n^{4}} <\dfrac{n+1}{n^2}\leq\dfrac{\left| n\right| +\left| n\right| }{|n|^{2}}=2\cdot \left| \dfrac{n}{n^{2}}\right| $ Is it okay? Can I make such an inequality or are there any solution? Thanks.

Comment: this seems okay to me, maybe with some qualification that n should be sufficiently large, and when you use triangle inequality, it would be $\leq$ not strict inequality.

Comment: Yeah you're right I'll fix it

Comment: You could also write it as $\dfrac{n^3(1+\frac{1}{n^3})}{n^4(1+\frac{4}{n^4})}\longrightarrow_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{n}\longrightarrow_{n \to \infty} 0$

Comment: Yeah but I asked to use epsilon definition. Not limit, also limit was given in the question. I want to reduce the sequence.

Comment: Sorry I missed that

Comment: Instead of $$\frac{n^3+1}{n^4}\lt\frac{n^3+n^2}{n^4}$$ why don't you just write $$\frac{n^3+1}{n^4}\le\frac{n^3+n^3}{n^4}=\frac2n\ ?$$ By the way, what's the point of putting absolute value signs on quantities you know are positive?

Comment: So you're saying we are working on $\mathbb{N}$, and there is no need to worry about negatives. Aren't you?

Comment: Thanks by the way, I understand what you meant by...

Comment: @beingmathematician Have you applied L'Hôpital's rule? Answer directly comes by applying it.

Comment: Yeah it can be, but I asked to use epsilon definition. Sorry, it's my bad, I didn't write any epsilon in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Almost you are reached out...

Let $\epsilon>0$. Let $N=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, Therefore for all $n>N$.

\begin{equation}
\left| \frac{n^3+1}{n^4+1}-0 \right|= \left| \frac{n^3+1}{n^4+1}\right|\leq 2\frac{1}{n}<2\frac{1}{N}=\epsilon. 
\end{equation}